# I cannot use a input check to verify if the person has put in the correct code

Tags: python, string, comparison

This is my code

```
name=""
name=input("What is your name?")
print ("For clarification, is your name",name,"?")
input("Please enter yes or no")
if input==("yes"):    
    print ("Thank you")
else:
    name=input("What is your name?")
```

---

and I was wondering if anyone could help me sort it out. In the lines below.

```
input("Please enter yes or no")
if input==("yes"):    
    print ("Thank you")
else:
    name=input("What is your name?")
    print ("Thank you",name,)
```

I am trying to ask people if they have put the correct names by asking them directly. If the answer is yes, they can move on, otherwise they will have to input their name again. Unfortunately I am not able to find the way to do it. Can anyone send me a correct code version. (An explanation would be nice but not necessary.)

Comment: Why do you think the call to `input` whose return value you don't save is any different from the call whose return value you assign to `name`?

Comment: if one answer solved your problem, please check it as correct anwer. Otherwise, give some more detail about your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
while True:
    n = input("Please enter yes or no")
    if n == "yes":    
        print ("Thank you")
        break
    else:
        name = input("What is your name?")
        print ("Thank you",name)
```

Comment: this would print first "Please enter yes or no". How to ask such a question ??

Answer (score 0):

You need to remember the second input to use it in the `if` statement.

```
response = input("Please enter yes or no")
if response == "yes":    
    print("Thank you")
else:
    name = input("What is your name?")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a recursive function.
It will loop until it returns the name.

```
#!python3
def get_name():
    name=input("What is your name?")
    print("For clarification, is your name",name,"?")
    sure = input("Please enter yes or no")
    if sure==("yes"):
        print("Thank you")
        return name
    else:
        get_name()

name = get_name()
```